Switching between the Android Apps based in Internet availability
We need to implement a logic to call one App from another based on the Internet connectivity.
For example, I have an APP A which is the main app, once I logged into that App , I will have a link to open two other apps based on internet availability. It means, if my Tab is connected to internet, I should be able to open Online App, else Offline app . That switch should be dynamic from Parent app i.e App A .
I believe that the problem statement is clear. Now question is, is it possible to implement that logic or not? If yes, please tell how I can do it.
Thanks in Advance.
I didn't try anything yet. I am checking the feasibility.

if(internet) startOnline() else startOffline().

If you want to know how to detect connectivity events, i did it like this:
abstract class ConnectivityMonitor(context: Context) {

    abstract fun onInternetAvailable()
    abstract fun onInternetLost()

    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .build()

    init {
        val callback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                super.onAvailable(network)
                onInternetAvailable()

            }
            // lost network connection
            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                onInternetLost()
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            (context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager::class.java) as ConnectivityManager).requestNetwork(networkRequest, callback)
        }
    }
}

